# Finding the angle $\angle DBA$

Tags: geometry

[image]

$ABCD$ represents a rectangle inside a quarter circle with center $O$. How can we find the angle $\angle DBA$?

To approach this problem, I realized that triangles $\triangle CDE$ and $\triangle EOA$ are similar and $\angle CDB= \angle DBA = x$. However, I do not see how these are helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F$ be symmetric to $C$ in $O$. Note that $CF$ is the diameter of the yellow circle. Since $\angle CBA=90^\circ$, it follows that $F,A,B$ are collinear.

Since $ABCD$ is rectangle, $x=\angle BAC$.

Note that $O,A,B,C$ lie on the circle with diameter $AC$. Hence $\angle BAC = \angle BOC$ as both angles subtend the arc $BC$ of this circle.

Now we angle-chase:

$$x=\angle BAC = \angle BOC = 2\angle BFC = 2(90^\circ - \angle FEA) = 180^\circ - 2\angle FEA = 180^\circ - 2(180^\circ - 125^\circ)=180^\circ - 2 \cdot 55^\circ = 70^\circ.$$

[image]

Comment: I understand the first part but not the second. Can you clarify the angles BAC and BOC?

Comment: @Keane I edited in more details. Let me know if it is clear now.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your so valuable thoughts. From what I understood, you are using basic angle theorems in circle

Comment: Without constructing $F$, recognize that $ABCDO$ is a cyclic quad, and we can do the angle chasing on it, using $BOC$ is isosceles.

Answer (score 2):

$\angle BOC=70^\circ$ because $\triangle BOC$ is isosceles and $\angle OCB=55^\circ$.

Let $P$ be the intersection of $AC$ and $BD$, then $|PO|=|AP|$ because    $P$ lies halfway between $O$ and $A$.

Then $\angle BAC=\angle BOC$ by [inscribed angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle) on $\circ P_O$ (as $A$ is on this circle).

---

Alternatively, $\angle CBA=90^\circ$, so $BA$ extended to the y-axis meets at the reflection of $C$ and is $35^\circ$.

But this angle is also the reflection of $\angle OCA$, so $\angle OCA=35^\circ$, and $\angle DCA=70^\circ$.